# How to verify contract field changes in a truffle test

Tags: solidity, truffle, unittesting

My contract is

```
contract SimpleContract {
    uint storedData;
    function set(uint x) public { storedData = x; }
    function get() public returns (uint) { return storedData; }
}
```

This test doesn't work:

```
var SimpleContract = artifacts.require("SimpleContract");

contract('SimpleContract', function(accounts) {
  let contract;
  let owner;
  let web3Contract;

  before(async () => {
    contract = await SimpleContract.deployed();
    web3Contract = web3.eth.contract(contract.abi).at(contract.address);
    owner = web3Contract._eth.coinbase;        
  });

  it("test", async function() {    
    await contract.set.call(10);    
    let result = await contract.get.call();
    assert.equal(result.toNumber(), 10, "updates the field");
  });  
});
```

I'm getting

**`AssertionError: fail: expected 0 to equal 10`**

Any idea?

Comment: Usevally call() is for get the value from state variable. It will not change state variable. If you want to change the state. Use contract.set.sendTransaction(args...,);

Comment: Cool @Jitendra, this solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jitendra Kumar. Balla's reply is the correct one. I was calling `set.call(10)` instead of `set.sendTransaction(10)`.